# Vim replace text on the fly ( "." => "->")

Tags: php, vim

I have this project in php I am working on and I find very annoying to type <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to call methods. I want to make vim do the job for me. I want it to replace `[^\s].` (non space + dot) with `->`.

Also, I the dollar var prefix annoys me and I wish I could replace `\s[a-z_]` (white space followed by lower A to Z and underscore) with `$` + the next letter I typed.

I.E.

```
a #=> $a
foo + bar # => $foo + $bar
this #=> $this
this.myMethod() #=> $this->myMethod()
```

That should happen only in php files, of course.

Is there a way to accomplish that? Something a little fancier than abbreviations maybe.

Comment: What did you try/research already?

Comment: So you want to type in javascript and insert in php, right?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem:

```
inoremap . ->
```

in your .vimrc would suffice. If you want it specific to php files:

```
filetype on
autocmd FileType php inoremap . ->
```

As for the second, I don't really see a way this can be written to work automatically.

Comment: Why the `<expr>`? Also, the first `FileType` should be lowercase.

Comment: Oh thanks, I will fix that. I just typed out some stuff quickly, I'll do some research on a proper way soon

Comment: @lightandlight. Thanks, I will try that. I edited the question and added an example that may answer your question. The example you asked, ```a_b``` whould become ```$a_b```

Comment: it says "E15: invalid expression >" and also "E15: invalid expression ->"

Comment: Yep sorry remove the <expr> and it works fine. I have not had access to vim today until now. Will get working on your second problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is good idea to handle your source code in this way, since it could destroy your codes, however for your requirement, this line do the two substitution you wanted:

```
%s/\v(\s|^)\ze[a-z_]/&$/g|%s/\./->/g
```

at least it works for the example you gave.

Comment: I will try that out, probably mixing solutions. I will be back soon to mark the most useful answer as correct. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Though you can build such "conditional remappings" with `:imap <expr>`, I highly recommend against doing that.

- Your stated rules are still way too simplistic; the first one wouldn't allow you to enter any comments like `Just a hack.` (would turn into `Just a hack->`). You'll spend more time (laboriously) tweaking your rules, or undoing  / suppressing the automatic conversion, just for saving a single keystroke here and there.
- Imagine yourself in another editor, debugger, a colleague's laptop. Now you're dependent on your auto-conversion scheme, and you'll look like a fool!

For me, it looks like you're coming from a different knowledge and still feel the beginner's pain of walking in unknown terrain. Persevere; you'll get over that soon!

Comment: Yeah, I understand that could cause me troubles, but I am happy to work that out for the sake of learning some more advanced VIM. Also the intelligence needed to keep me lazy should be aware of "strigs that cannot turn into $strings". I am not a beginner in PHP, I have some years of experience and trust me, ```->``` will always be a PIA. For the moment I Mapped ```imap .. -><cr>``` and it is working good. Thank you for the advice :). I'll be trying things out for a few days until I chose the best answer.